# Jmeter: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter, sslhandshakeexception

I am using JMeter 5.4.2 and using Jdk8 but I am getting `avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` when I try to hit a soap service. I dont have control over the remote server and I am wondering if I can change anything in the client side to make this work. Tried to look Jre java.security file but I don't see TLS1.0 in the disabled list:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768
```

This is my exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.g.a(g.java:28)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.g.a(g.java:48)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:33)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:81)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:187)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a2$b.b(a2$b.java:41)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a2$b.consume(a2$b.java:21)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.p.consume(p.java:58)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aa.a(aa.java:207)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aa.a(aa.java:287)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:195)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a0.a(a0.java:43)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bj.b(bj.java:8)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bj.f(bj.java:81)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bj.a(bj.java:55)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bj.startHandshake(bj.java:20)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
```

Comment: This should be addressed server side.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.0 support was [removed](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html#JDK-8202343) in [Java 11](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/11/)

My java.security configuration from [Microsoft OpenJDK implementation](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk) looks like:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

So either you need to remove this `TLSv1` bit from there or downgrade to an earlier Java version, [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) needs Java 8 to run.

Comment: I heard by default JMeter uses TLSv1.2 but is there any way I can change that to TLSv1 in JMeter ? I am using JDK8 and I dont see TLSv1 in the list